# Enabling of renderscript makes app to ignore jniLibs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-native-interface, renderscript

I want to use some jni libraries. So I put binaries like this:

```
project
-app
--jnilibs
---armeabi
----libqwerty.so
```

and in my build.gradle (app module):

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
}
```

it works as expected, however when I add renderscript to my project:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 22
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

application doesn't see my jniLibs directory anymore. And the content of `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir` is: `[libRSSupport.so, librsjni.so]`

**UPDATE:** ok, I was able to resolve this issue with just renaming directory `armeabi` to `armeabi-v7a`. However what if I want to support some other cpu-architectures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [answer](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68520#c1) by a  Google developer: renderscript libraries are not supported for Arm v6 and they have no plans to port them back. As for x86, MIPS, and 64-bit versions, Gradle will automagically add appropriate RS binaries to your APK.

Comment: so I just have to create separate folders for each cpu?

Comment: You only have to specify the **abiFIlters** for **android.ndk**. You can also use the [ABI splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) to generate separate APKs for different CPUs.